# SQL Join query using three tables and some null values

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in a mySQL database that I am querying with PHP:

**players**

```
player_id | player_name
-----------------------
1           Tom
2           Dick
3           Harry
```

**games**

```
game_id | game_name
-------------------
1         Tennis
2         Cricket
3         Rugby
```

**gamePlayerRel**

```
game_id | player_id
-------------------
1         2
1         3
2         3
3         2
3         3
```

I want a query that will return the players id and name as well as the games that they play. If they play no games - as in the case of Tom (1) - then I want the id and name and a `null` or `0` value.

**Desired Result**

```
player_id | player_name | game_id | game_name
---------------------------------------------
1           Tom           null      null
2           Dick          1         Tennis
2           Dick          3         Rugby
3           Harry         1         Tennis
3           Harry         2         Cricket
3           Harry         3         Rugby
```

The closest I can get is with the following query:

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, gamePlayerRel.game_id, games.game_name
FROM players
INNER JOIN gamePlayerRel
INNER JOIN games
ON players.player_id = gamePlayerRel.player_id
AND gamePlayerRel.game_id=games.game_id
```

This gets close except that it does not return data for players with games assigned to them. In the above examples the result is as I want except that Tom (1) with his `null` values is left out.

I'm a super noob at this so if I'm coming at it from the wrong angle please say so and if you can suggest a query that will do what I'm after you would make my day.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return the result set as you've shown you need to actually do two outer joins

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, gamePlayerRel.game_id, games.game_name
FROM players
    LEFT OUTER JOIN gamePlayerRel ON players.player_id = gamePlayerRel.player_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON gamePlayerRel.game_id=games.game_id
```

In your case this should work just fine, however, what I really think you're trying to do is an inner join between games and gamePlayerRel and then a Left Outer Join between that virtual table and the players table.  You can accomplish that via something like this:

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, playerGames.game_id,      playerGames.game_name
FROM players
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select gameplayerRel.player_id, games.game_id, games.game_name  from games inner join gamePlayerRel on games.game_id = gamePlayerRel.game_id) playerGames
       on players.player_id = playerGames.player_id
```

In your case you'd never need this alternative syntax, but there are some times when things can get messed up because the two left outer joins way is not exactly logically equivalent.

Here is a SQL Fiddle showing the [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/da71e/2) of the queries

I know you're using mysql, but this article does a good job of explaining the nuances of the joins, but it is written for MSSQL, although it should apply to you just the same.  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, gamePlayerRel.game_id, games.game_name
FROM players
    INNER JOIN gamePlayerRel ON players.player_id = gamePlayerRel.player_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON gamePlayerRel.game_id=games.game_id
```

You need to join each table individually and also need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for your games table. This will pull in at least one record for every match in the players/gamePlayerRel tables. If there isn't a match you'll be returned a `NULL` value.

Comment: Cheers for this. I tried it and it was close but didn't return any data for the entry that was not linked to a game type. I have been prodding it since then and have finally got the result I was after. I'll post below in case anyone else is interested.

Answer (score 0):

After being nudged in the right direction by the helpful folk of SO I have got a query that does what I am after though I am still not 100% sure *why* it works.

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, gamePlayerRel.game_id, games.game_name
FROM players
INNER JOIN gamePlayerRel ON players.player_id = gamePlayerRel.player_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON gamePlayerRel.game_id=games.game_id
```

Thanks to those who commented. Once again this site proves one of the most useful I have ever found :)

Comment: For anyone else struggling to get their head around joins - hopefully it's not just me - I have found [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) quite helpful.

Comment: I believe your solution is the exact solution I posted.

Comment: Well now I'm embarrassed. I swear I tried yours and it didn't return any null values until I had played around with it for a while. It is very possible that I had a special moment and was checking the wrong code or something. I'll double check tomorrow when I'm back at work and then mark your answer as correct. Sorry for trying to steal your glory, it was entirely unintentional :)

Comment: The query you've posted doesn't return null values.  See this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/da71e/3

Comment: Somewhere along the line I have got rather in a pickle with all this. The query I posted here is indeed the same one as was suggested by @MattBusche and doesn't return any `null` values. I think I copied the one from the answer to paste into phpMyAdmin and then pasted it back when I tried to answer my own question. Confusion ensued.